# MVVM WPF Richtextbox change text color

Tags: c#, mvvm, wpf-controls, richtextbox

I have a Richtext box that is placed in a usercontrol:

```
<RichTextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                        FontFamily="Courier New" FontSize="13" IsReadOnly="True" Margin="5,0" Name="richTxtBoxValue" >
            <FlowDocument TextAlignment="Left">
                <Paragraph>
                    <Run  Text="{Binding Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"> </Run>
                </Paragraph>
            </FlowDocument>
        </RichTextBox>
```

I now need to change the color of some text in this richtextbox. I tried the following code. But I am getting startPos and endPos as null.

```
var textRange = RichTxtBoxValue.Selection;
var start = RichTxtBoxValue.Document.ContentStart;
var startPos = start.GetPositionAtOffset(startPosition);
var endPos = start.GetPositionAtOffset(startPosition+1);
textRange.Select(startPos, endPos);
textRange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red));
```

I am unable to figure out where I am going wrong.

Comment: how are you calculating startPosition ?

Comment: It would help if you posted more code snippets as it is unclear where the second code snippet is being executed.